# How can I parse a java property file with php?

Tags: php

Hi I have a little problem in parsing my java property file the right way. I need an Array for every id, because I want to store everything in my SQL database. I am posting you what I achieved until now. Maybe you have an idea how to do it the right way:

Content of 01.meta:

```
12345.fileName=myfile.jpg
12345.path=files/myfile.jpg
12346.fileName=myfile2.jpg
12346.path=files/myfile2.jpg
```

my php:

```
<?php                   
    $file_path = "files/01.meta";
    $lines = explode("\n", trim(file_get_contents($file_path)));
    $properties = array();

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $line = trim($line);

        if (!$line || substr($line, 0, 1) == '#') // skip empty lines and comments
        continue;

        if (false !== ($pos = strpos($line, '='))) {
            $properties[trim(substr($line, 0, $pos))] = trim(substr($line, $pos + 1));
        }
    }

    print_r($properties);
?>
```

The result:

```
Array ( [12345.fileName] => myfile.jpg [12345.path] => files/myfile.jpg [12346.fileName] => myfile2.jpg [12346.path] => files/myfile2.jpg )
```

What I would need:

```
Array ( [id] => 12345 [fileName] => myfile.jpg [path] => files/myfile.jpg )
Array ( [id] => 12346 [fileName] => myfile2.jpg [path] => files/myfile2.jpg )
```

Comment: Have a look at `parse_ini_file()`: http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: @Typoheads: Thank you, I looked at the link you sent me but I could only find out how to parse all the signs infront of the equalsign

Comment: Have a closer look at the comments section. I think this might be perfect in your case: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#114842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant approach than my last one would be the following:

```
$file_path = "files/01.meta";
$linesArray = file($file_path);    // $linesArray is an array   
$properties = array();

foreach ($linesArray AS $line) {
    if (false !== ($pos = strpos($line, '='))) {
        $prop=array();    // create array ro receive one line 
        $prop[trim(substr($line, 0, $pos))] = trim(substr($line, $pos + 1));
        $lineContArray = explode("=", $line);
        $identArray = explode(".", $lineContArray[0]);

        $ident = $identArray[0];
        $type = $identArray[1];     

        $value = $lineContArray[1];

        $found = 0;
        for ($i=0; $i<count($properties); $i++) {
            if ($properties[$i]['id'] == $ident) {
                $properties[$i][$type]= $value;
                $found=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($found == 0) {
            $properties[] = array('id' => $ident, $type => $value);
        }
    }
}
```

This one has the advantage that the elements in your file can be in arbitrary order.

Comment: Thank you! Great! Can I ask you one more question? At the end of my file I want to parse also the fileSize written like this: fileSize=1024595340. With your code I will get: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 12345 [fileName] => myfile.jpg [path] => files/myfile.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 12346 [fileName] => myfile2.jpg [path] => files/myfile2.jpg ) [2] => Array ( [id] => fileSize [] => 1024595340 ) ) ` Is it possible to get the filesize like this `[fileSize] => 1024595340`. Acutally I achieved this with my code above, but I do not know how to combine my code with yours.

Comment: ugly, but functional: replace the last condition with this: if ($found == 0) {
    if (is_numeric($ident)) {
     $properties[] = array('id' => $ident, $type => $value);
    } else {
     $properties[] = array($ident => $value);
    }
   }

Comment: Glad i could help :-)

Comment: Oh I saw that the solution is not working, because my id is not alway a number. Sometime it is something like this 0001421DB21302FG12

Comment: Maybe I can do it like this: if ($ident=="fileSize")?

Comment: in this case, near the end of the script (the addition from my comment) replace `if (is_numeric($ident)) {` with `if (!empty($type)) {`

Comment: Thank you, I do not know why this is working :) but I will try to learn now. Does it mean that if infront of the point it is empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84707/discussion-between-burki-and-jarla).

Comment: (feel free to join the chat. i will try to explain everything you would like to know there: SO does not like lengthy comment lists)

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
$file_path = "files/01.meta";
$linesArray = file($file_path);    // $linesArray is an array
$properties = array();

$helper = array();

foreach ($linesArray AS $line) {
    if (false !== ($pos = strpos($line, '='))) {
        $prop=array();    // create array ro receive one line 
        $prop[trim(substr($line, 0, $pos))] = trim(substr($line, $pos + 1));

        $lineContArray = explode("=", $line);
        $identArray = explode(".", $lineContArray[0]);

        $ident = $identArray[0];
        $type = $identArray[1];     
        $value = $lineContArray[1];

        if (isset($helper['id']) && $ident != $helper['id'])  {
            $properties[] = $helper;
            unset($helper);
        }
        $helper['id'] = $ident;
        $helper[$type]= $value;
    }
}
if (!empty($helper)) {
    $properties[] = $helper;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, I tried the code and with `print_r($properties);`I get an empty white page as an result

Comment: sorry, there was a bug in this line: `if (isset($helper['id']) && $ident != $currentID)  {`  
would you like to try again?

Comment: Thank you, here is the result I get: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [12345.fileName] => myfile.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [12345.path] => files/myfile.jpg ) [2] => Array ( [12346.fileName] => myfile2.jpg ) [3] => Array ( [12346.path] => files/myfile2.jpg ) [4] => Array ( [id] => [] => files/myfile2.jpg ) ) `

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks almost perfect: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [12345.fileName] => myfile.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [12345.path] => files/myfile.jpg ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 12345 [fileName] => myfile.jpg ) [3] => Array ( [12346.fileName] => myfile2.jpg ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 12345 [path] => files/myfile.jpg ) [5] => Array ( [12346.path] => files/myfile2.jpg ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 12346 [fileName] => myfile2.jpg ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 12346 [path] => files/myfile2.jpg ) ) ` .

Comment: hmm... one more edit... if that still doesn't work as expected i may need to test before posting :-)

Comment: Here is the new result: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [12345.fileName] => myfile.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [12345.path] => files/myfile.jpg ) [2] => Array ( [12346.fileName] => myfile2.jpg ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 12345 [fileName] => myfile.jpg [path] => files/myfile.jpg ) [4] => Array ( [12346.path] => files/myfile2.jpg ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 12346 [fileName] => myfile2.jpg [path] => files/myfile2.jpg ) ) `

Comment: Array [3] and [5] are actually perfect what I need. We just would need to remove the other arrays. I will try to find out the reason also

Comment: So. now i tested and debugged it :-) It should be working now. (it does on my system, at least)

Comment: Wonderful! I am so happy!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sort($lines);    
$properties = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i+=2) {
    $properties[] = array(
        "id" => current(explode(".",$lines[$i])),
        "filename" => next(explode("=",$lines[$i])),
        "path" => next(explode("=",$lines[$i+1]))
    );
}

printf("<pre>%s</pre>", print_r($properties,true));
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12345
            [filename] => myfile.jpg
            [path] => files/myfile.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12346
            [filename] => myfile2.jpg
            [path] => files/myfile2.jpg
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not working if my lines mix up the order. My files look always different

Comment: Can't you just sort them? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Thank you so much, the user Burki posted a solution I needed

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Just thought I could add a shorter solution that in my opinion is easier to read. It works with the lines in mixed up order ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think your solution is also fine